# How to split using partial fractions: $\frac{9x^2+48x+18}{(2x+1)(x^2+8x+3)}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, self-learning

I'm self-studying from Stroud & Booth's amazing "Engineering Mathematics", but am stuck on a problem from the "Partial Fractions" chapter.

I've been running around in circles trying to solve it, and just can't seem to get it right (although I understand the general mechanics around the solution process).

The expression that I need to split into partial fractions is:

$$\frac{9x^2+48x+18}{(2x+1)(x^2+8x+3)}$$

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: This is not an equation.

Comment: An **equa**tion "**equa**tes" a (left hand side) LHS to a RHS with an **equa**l sign.

Comment: I think neuron wants to find the partial fractions as he has stated in the body of the question, probably misunderstood about equation

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming you want to split it into partial fractions)

Let $$\frac{9x^2+48x+18}{(2x+1)(x^2+8x+3)} = \frac{a}{2x+1} + \frac{bx+c}{x^2+8x+3}$$

By inspection,

At $x=-\frac{1}{2}$,

$$\frac{9/4-48/2+18}{1/4-8/2+3} = a\implies a = 5$$

At $x=0$

$$\frac{0+0+18}{(0+1)(0+0+3)} = \frac{5}{0+1}+\frac{c}{0+0+3}\implies c =3 $$

At $x=1$

$$\frac{9+48+18}{3(1+8+3)} = \frac{5}{3}+\frac{b+3}{1+8+3}\implies b=2$$

So, $$\frac{9x^2+48x+18}{(2x+1)(x^2+8x+3)} = \frac{5}{2x+1} + \frac{2x+3}{x^2+8x+3}$$

Comment: You should explain how you know the thing _has_ a partial fractions expansion of that form!

Comment: For example, $\frac{x}{(x-1)(x^2-1)}=\frac a{x-1}+\frac{bx+c}{x^2-1}$ will not work...